# Proving $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

While proving that $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ for every integer $a$, can we prove it as consequence of the following: we know that
$$(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p\pmod p \hskip1cm \mbox{ for } x,y\in\mathbb{Z},$$
and by induction, we can show that
$$
(x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n)^p \equiv x_1^p + \cdots + x_n^p \pmod p.
$$
Thus, for any integer $a$, positive or negative, we take all $x_i$'s to be $1$ or $-1$ accordingly, and arrive at the conclusion that
$$a^p\equiv a\pmod p.$$
**Q.** Is there any problem in this argument?

(**Why this question came?** I am familiar with other arguments. But, when  I revisited the $p$-th power congruence relation for sum $x+y$ as above,  I was thinking can we state its consequence as the Fermat's little theorem.)

Comment: Yes, if you know the $(x+y)^p$ result, you can prove the other result by induction. You don’t need to go through the $x_1,\dots,x_n$ steps. Straight induction works for the non-negative $a,$ and it is easy to prove it for negative numbers as a result of the positive numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for comments and confirmation.

Comment: For coprime $a$ you just multiply Fermat's little by $a$.   For $a=0$ it follows that any $n\neq 0$ gives $0$ as a remainder...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The intent was here to prove a version of Fermat's little theorem by induction , so it would be circular to use it.